# Obtain undefined value of the App_initialize service when the lazy load module is used

Tags: angular

the goal is to load the configuration from the json file and it works fine when I only had one module, But when I divided my application into 2 modules and used the lazy loading module, I got undefined values of the configuration-loader.service

configuration-loader.service.ts

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ConfigurationLoaderService {

  private readonly CONFIGURATION_URL = "../../assets/config/config.json";
  private configuration: Config;

  constructor(private _http: HttpClient) {  }

  public loadConfiguration() {
    return this._http.get(this.CONFIGURATION_URL).toPromise().then( (configuration: any) => {
        this.configuration = configuration;
        return configuration;
      })
      .catch((error: any) => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  }

  getConfiguration() {
    return this.configuration;
  }
}
```

app-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    loadChildren: () => import('./Auth/auth.module').then((m) => m.AuthModule),
  },
  {
    path: 'messenger',
    loadChildren: () => import('./Msn/msn.module').then((m) => m.MsnModule),
  },
 
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

app.module.ts

```
import { GoogleLoginProvider, SocialAuthServiceConfig, SocialLoginModule } from '@abacritt/angularx-social-login';
import { APP_INITIALIZER, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { StoreModule } from '@ngrx/store';
import { EffectsModule } from '@ngrx/effects';
import { StoreRouterConnectingModule } from '@ngrx/router-store';
import { StoreDevtoolsModule } from '@ngrx/store-devtools';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';
import { JwtHelperService, JWT_OPTIONS } from '@auth0/angular-jwt';
import { ConfigurationLoaderService } from './services/configuration-loader.service';
import { AppReducer } from './state/app.state';
import { AuthEffects } from './Auth/state/auth.effects';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { NgxSpinnerModule } from 'ngx-spinner';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from "@angular/platform-browser/animations";
import { TagInputModule } from 'ngx-chips';
import { SimpleModalModule } from 'ngx-simple-modal';
import { ToastrModule } from 'ngx-toastr';
import { NgxSkeletonLoaderModule } from 'ngx-skeleton-loader';

export function loadConfiguration(configService: ConfigurationLoaderService) {
  return () => configService.loadConfiguration();
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    SocialLoginModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    SocialLoginModule,
    NgxSpinnerModule,
    TagInputModule,
    NgxSkeletonLoaderModule,
    // TooltipModule.forRoot({'show-delay': 250 }),
    ToastrModule.forRoot({ timeOut: 2000 }),
    SimpleModalModule.forRoot({container: "modal-container"}),

    StoreModule.forRoot(AppReducer),

    StoreDevtoolsModule.instrument({ maxAge: 25, logOnly: environment.production }),

    EffectsModule.forRoot([AuthEffects]),
  ],
  providers: [
    { 
      provide: JWT_OPTIONS,
       useValue: JWT_OPTIONS 
    },
    //so we can change API and hub URLs without redeploying the app
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: loadConfiguration, 
      deps: [ConfigurationLoaderService],
      multi: true
    },
    JwtHelperService
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

the json file

```
{
    "apiUrl": "https://localhost:44382/api/",
    "baseUrl": "https://localhost:44382",
    "hubChatUrl": "https://localhost:44382/chat"
}
```

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.